# Tunnel network from VirtualBox to Ubuntu Host

Tags: networking, virtualbox-networking

I have Windows VM running in VirtualBox on my  Ubuntu host. On the guest VM, I have Pulse Secure VPN to connect to my office network. There is a client for Linux too, but that doesn't work very well.

I want all the traffic from my host machine to be routed via the VPN in my guest machine. Is this possible even? If yes, how?

Comment: I highly doubt that this is possible because the VM relies on the host to connect to the internet. In theory, it's possible with bridges, but would be less reliable than just trying to get the VPN to work on your host. Try and see if your office can provide an OpenVPN or L2TP tunnel.

Answer (score 0):

I would add a bridged adapter on the windows guest. That way, it will get an IP address that is reachable in your LAN.

Comment: I am not an expert when it comes to networking. Would your solution allow me to route all the traffic from host through the VPN connected guest?

Comment: Yes. With the bridged adapter your guest will get an IP address in the same range as your local network. It's will be seen as a seperate computer

Comment: I tried and I can ping my vm from host. My host in connected to VPN. Now I want all my traffic in host to be routed through the VPN.

Comment: you must replace the default gateway with the IP of your VPN box